# Can not call Django view function via/ using ajax function

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

**views.py:**

```
def post_upload(request, resolution, format, size):
    print(resolution)
    print(format)
    print(size)
    return render(request, 'upload .html')
```

**urls.py:**

```
path(r'^post_upload/$', views.post_upload, name='post_upload')
```

**give.js:**

```
$(".btn").bind('click', function(){

    console.log('download button clicked');

    var resolution = $(this).closest("tr").find(".resolution").text();
    var format = $(this).closest("tr").find(".format").text();
    var size = $(this).closest("tr").find(".size").text();
    var csrf_token = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();


    console.log(resolution,format,size, csrf_token);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
     url : "{% url 'post_upload' %}",
     data: {
        resolution: resolution,
        format: format,
        size: size,
     },
     dataType:"html",
     success: function(data, status, xhr){
        //do something with your data
    }
    });

    return false;
});
```

**html code:**
In this button created dynamically.

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="button"  name="url" value="{{ request.GET.url }}"  type="submit" id="download" class="btn btn-success" >Download</button>
</form>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'%} "></script>

    <script src="{% static 'js/plugin.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https:cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/give.js' %}"></script>
```

I can try to call post_upload() function in views.py using or via ajax fuction which is save as give.js. But In this error like this Not Found : /{% url 'post_update' }

and 404

Comment: Don't just show your code. Explain what you are trying to do and what happend?

Comment: i can not call my django function using ajax

Comment: That can mean anything. Be specific.

Comment: i can try to call post_upload() view function, using ajax

Comment: No. You cannot as your scripts are external for django template syntax to work.

Comment: Then, which syntax i can use

Comment: The `path` does not make much sense: `path` does not work with a regex, so it makes more sense to work with `path('post_upload/', views.post_upload, name='post_upload')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path makes no sense, since the [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) works with path syntax, *not* a regular expression. Furthermore you can not use [**`{% url … %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) in the `.js` file, since the JavaScript file is simply returned, it is not rendered.

This thus means that you rewrite the path to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('post_upload/', views.post_upload, name='post_upload')
    # …
]
```

and in the `give.js` file, we work with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : '/post_upload/',
    # …
});
```